# Custom Shipping Method - Retrieve Shipping address in collectRates

Tags: php, magento2

I'm currently working on a custom shipping method for Magento 2 and I'm facing a problem : I don't know how to retrieve the shipping address.

I tried first with something like this in the `collectRates()` method :

```
$city = $request->getDestCity();
$street = $request->getDestStreet();
$postCode = $request->getDestPostcode();
```

But it didn't worked (`$city` and `$street` are empty).

That's strange because I don't have any issue whit the `getDestPostcode()` method.

Is there a another way to retrieve the shipping address ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hum.. No one knows ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this?

```
$shippingId =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
$address = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Address')-     >load($shippingId);
echo "<pre>";print_r($address->getData());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As per Pallavi's answer but with more detail.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
 */
protected $customerSession;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager $objectManager
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
    $this->rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
}

// ...

/**
 * @param RateRequest $request
 * @return bool|Result
 */
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getActiveFlag()) {
        // This shipping method is disabled in the configuration
        return false;
    }


    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier(self::SHIPPING_CODE);
    // Get the title from the configuration, as defined in system.xml
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod(self::SHIPPING_CODE);
    // Get the title from the configuration, as defined in system.xml
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    // Get the price from the configuration, as defined in system.xml
    $amount = $this->getConfigData('price');

    // Get the customer session and shipping address as specified.
    $address =  $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getAddressById();
    // Note: shippingId will be null on guest checkouts.
    // Request to estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id will send it.


     file_put_contents('mydebug.json', '--------------------------\nRequest: \n'.json_encode($request->getData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
     file_put_contents('mydebug.json', '--------------------------\nCustomer Address: \n'.json_encode($address->getData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);


    $method->setPrice($amount);
    $method->setCost($amount);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;

}
```

You will need to run a di compile after changing the constructors dependencies/args.

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Notes:

Need JS mixin files to send any custom attributes over as well if using those.

getDefaultShipping() returns null on guest checkout.

I ended up checking the URL as well.

```
    // Get the data from post input via php://input
    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $postData = json_decode($request_body, true);


if (preg_match("/^\/rest\/default\/V1\/carts\/mine\/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
            $address =  $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getAddressById($postData['addressId']);
            if ($address) {
                file_put_contents('liamsdebug.json', '--------------------------\nCustomer Address: \n'.json_encode($address->getData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            }
        }
```